# How to get Python module install directory in CMake?

Tags: python, cmake

I have created a small Python module using C++ and Boost, built with CMake. Now I need to install it into standard python modules directory, however it needs to be a path inside `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, so it can be packaged with standard Debian packaging system.

Now I have this, where the last line is obviously wrong, as it is an absolute path to a system directory.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(foo)

# Not Shown: Extract ${PYTHON_VERSION} from interpreter

find_package(Python ${PYTHON_VERSION} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)

find_package(Boost 1.55.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system python${Python_VERSION_MAJOR}${Python_VERSION_MINOR})

Python_add_library(foo MODULE
    src/foo.cc src/python_interface.cc
)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
target_link_libraries(foo
    PUBLIC
        Boost::python${Python_VERSION_MAJOR}${Python_VERSION_MINOR}
)

# This is wrong
install(TARGETS foo DESTINATION ${Python_SITEARCH}/foo)
```

I also had a look at Python's `distutils` and `setuptools`, however they don't seem suited to standalone use.

Comment: "it needs to be a relative path to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX" -- not really... why do you think so?

Comment: @zaufi It is supposed to go into a package and `make install` will be called without root privileges

Comment: `make install` performed by the CPack uses `DESTDIR` to install the files to an "image directory" which is going to be packed later... so don't worry.

Comment: what I see in your example project looks quite correct to me

Comment: Actually CPack is not called at all, everything is built with `dpkg-buildpackage` system. Calling it with the code above results in error in copying the file.

Comment: Then it is time to use CPack to build the package %)
Or at least run `make install` from the deb-helper's w/ `DESTDIR` %)

Comment: I use CPack to make Deb/RPM/Nuget/Zip packages just having a CMake configuration... easy-peasy %) -- no need to deal w/ "native" package build tools at all

Comment: @zaufi Thanks for the kick, DESTDIR was indeed the right solution, and it is used by `debhelper` by default, which I missed. Want to make this an answer?

Comment: I don't know your case (why do you want debhelpers vs CPack... my only guess you are a distromaker %), so if you consider `DESTDIR` is an answer to your question, ok let it be the answer )